# Not able to add constraints in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

my table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE USER
(
 id            INTEGER,
 name          VARCHAR(50),
 gender        VARCHAR(2),
 dateofbirth   DATE,
 song_id       INTEGER,
 ratings       INTEGER
);



CREATE TABLE song
(
  id             INTEGER,
  name           VARCHAR(50),
  lengthofsong   INTEGER,
  album_id       INTEGER
);
```

my constraints adding query:

```
ALTER TABLE USER  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_song_id FOREIGN KEY(song_id) REFERENCES song(id);
```

error i'm getting:

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command: ALTER TABLE USER 
>   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_song_id FOREIGN KEY(song_id) REFERENCES song(id)
>
> Can't create table 'test.#sql-4f7_33' (errno: 150)

Execution time: 0.1s

1 statement failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a primary  key   the error 150 is related to the fact you don't have a proper primary keys for constrains

```
CREATE TABLE USER
(
   id            INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name          VARCHAR(50),
   gender        VARCHAR(2),
   dateofbirth   DATE,
   song_id       INTEGER,
   ratings       INTEGER,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);



CREATE TABLE song
(
 id             INTEGER  INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name           VARCHAR(50),
 lengthofsong   INTEGER,
 album_id       INTEGER
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not create a foreign key to simple field the must be a primary key :
so the id of the song must be primary key so can create a foreign key reference to it

```
drop table user;
CREATE TABLE USER
(
 id            int,
 name          VARCHAR(50),
 gender        VARCHAR(2),
 dateofbirth   DATE,
 song_id       int,
 ratings       int
);

drop table song;
CREATE TABLE song
(
  id             int primary key ,
  name           VARCHAR(50),
  lengthofsong   int,
  album_id       int
);


ALTER TABLE USER  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_song_id FOREIGN KEY(song_id) REFERENCES song(id);
```

i'm late i think ^^